# Views exposed filter redirects to wrong url

Tags: 7, views, panels

After submitting the filter settings, on a page (panel in ctools Page manager module) with view content pane, the filter path (in URL) instead of being applied to the current page (with view), it is added to the root domain (home page).

Please give a tip what might be wrong with settings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

View Settings - PANE SETTINGS (middle column) - Use Panel path:Yes